# Copy/Paste MMA code from PDF into Notebook garbles special characters

Tags: front-end, notebooks, pdf-format, fonts

I have a PDF which contains Mathematica code and plain text. It was probably generated directly from one or more Notebooks. I am running MMA 13.1 on Ubuntu, and when I copy/paste any of the plain text it works perfectly. When I try to copy/paste a Mathematica command, the letters and numbers appear correctly, but special characters like [] {} # and @ are garbled. For example,

I copied the following line from the PDF:

```
Plus @@ # & /@ {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 5}}
```

And when pasted into the Notebook it appears as:

```
Plus üü Ò & êü 881, 2, 3<, 82, 3, 4, 5<, 89, 10, 11, 12<<
```

The Properties tab in Adobe Reader shows that copying of content is allowed, so it doesn’t seem to be a question of copy protection deliberately garbling the contents. An internet search revealed that another user had experienced the identical problem:

[Exported PDF copy-and-pastable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39417/exported-pdf-copy-and-pastable)

In his answer, “@Alexey Popkov” suggested running this command:

`Style["8@", FontFamily -> "Mathematica2Mono"]`

in a Notebook. This comes out as “{[“.

I tried this with the command above, substituting all the different Mathematica font names from /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/13.1/SystemFiles/Fonts/TrueType, but none of them produced a good result.
The PDF file is from approximately 2010, probably MMA 6 or 7. I opened the PDF in Windows with Adobe Reader and used the File -> Properties -> Fonts command. I saw references to Mathematica1, Mathematica2, Mathematica3 and Mathematica4 (with or without Sans, Bold, Mono). Is it possible that MMA exported some now obsolete fonts which became embedded in the PDF?

I would be very grateful to find a solution which would allow me to copy and paste from my PDF into a Notebook. Is it possible?
`

Comment: Could you please link the PDF in question here?

Comment: @VictorK. The book by Leonid is one of the PDFs I see this problem with. Attempting to copy/paste any MMA command will demonstrate it. <https://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/download/MathProgrammingIntro.pdf>

Comment: The book is also available online as .html at the same site. If you copy/paste Mathematica code from the web page into a notebook, it shows up as a .gif file, not text. That suggests that you may be trying to copy/paste an image from your .pdf file as well, which might explain why you're running into difficulties. I can copy explanatory text from the web page fine - no scrambling. But the equations do get garbled - probably because you need to somehow convert from .gif format to text format.